# Make jquery.eraser work on hover rather than click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jQuery.eraser](http://minimal.be/lab/jQuery.eraser/) which works well to erase an image. But it works on click rather than hover. I thought I would be able to trigger a click on hover so it clicked where the mouse is. But what I have tried is not working. I am presuming I need to feed it some coordinates to work?

This is what I have tried:

```
$( "#image1" ).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){ 

$(this).trigger( "click" );

})
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r35kntxm/) of a working example.

Answer (score 1):

In the "bind events" section of `eraser` code, replace the bindings to the following:

```js
$canvas.bind('mouseenter.eraser', methods.mouseDown);
$canvas.bind('mouseenter.eraser', methods.touchStart);
$canvas.bind('touchmove.eraser', methods.touchMove);
$canvas.bind('mouseleave.eraser', methods.touchEnd);
```

This seems to work on a laptop, however you should be aware that this is a quick and ugly fix, I am not sure how it will behave on mobile devices, and you should think twice before using it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q49w1cuj/